# Javascript html dom elements array for in loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom, for-in-loop, nodelist

So let's say I have an array of DOM elements:

```
var z = document.getElementsByClassName('name');
```

and for each element I want to set attribute with for in loop:

```
for(var n in z){z[n].setAttribute('marked', '1');}
```

For above code I get `z[n].setAttibute is not a function`. However when I manually check in console elements of z array, `marked` attribute has been added to each element. Why is that happening and how can I prevent such error from happening?

Comment: n is the element, not an index, do n.setAttribute. You should use a traditional counter for for a nodelist

Comment: A nodelist is array-like, using a regular for-loop is probably more appropriate.

Comment: See [Why is using “for…in” with array iteration a bad idea?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/500504/1529630)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`document.getElementsByClassName` returns an instance of [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection), an array-like object. `for..in` loop was designed for objects, not arrays. It iterates through all properties of an object. Therefore, when iterating through HTMLCollection, besides array indexes you get also other properties, like `length`. As `length` is simply a number, it doesn't have `setAttribute` method, so you get that error.

You should either use a regular `for` loop, or `for..of` loop:

```
const z = document.getElementsByClassName('name')

// Regular loop:
for (let i = 0, len = z.length; i < len; i++) {
  z[i].setAttribute('marked', '1')
}

// for..of loop:
for (const element of z) {
  element.setAttribute('marked', '1')
}
```

You can also convert HTMLCollection to array using [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from). Then you can use all array methods on it, for example [`.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

```
const z = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('name'))

z.forEach(element=> element.setAttribute('marked', '1'))
```

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns a `HTMLCollection`, not a `NodeList`. The difference is relevant because DOM4 made NodeList [iterable](http://heycam.github.io/webidl/#idl-iterable), so you can use `forEach` directly.

Comment: thank you Michal, FYI i really like Poland...

Answer (score 0):

```
[].forEach.call(z, function(el) {
 el.setAttribute('marked', '1');
})
```

for..in will get all the keys of the HTMLCollection, including the property .length. .length is a Number and doesn't have a .setAttribute function.